# How to see Firebase event object as it is with all parameters together?

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use Firebase analytics with my mobile game app (Swift on iOS). I've created several custom events and some of them have multiple parameters. For example I made an event named `start_level` when player starts playing a new level. It has 2 parameters: `level_number` and `world_name`. Data is being populated into Firebase web console inside `start_level` event records but it doesn't show me mapping from `level_number` to `world_name`. So basically I would know what level numbers were played by users and what worlds were played by users individually but no information about which level number is played in which world by user.

I tried to read up Firebase documentation but it isn't clear to me about how to view this information. Is this kind of information only available with BigQuery (which isn't supported for free accounts)? It seems to be a very trivial thing to put only in paid version of Firebase provided I can easily workaround it by concatenating world name and level number and sending it as one parameter.

Any help/info regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is probably your best option.  If you concatenate the level number with the world name, be aware of the [500 event type limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event).
Note that smaller uses of BigQuery are likely to cost [little or nothing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).